# Can Telomers be tampered with using Nano technology?

Tags: cancer, treatment, practice-of-medicine, genetic-engineering

Can Telomers be tampered with using Nano particles or nano robots that can be artificially used to CAUSE cancer?
I happen to run into this website
Talking about nano technology based cancer research.
https://www.google.com/amp/s/mariakonovalenko.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/life-extension-through-nanotechnology/amp/

This is 9 years old though. 
Just wondering this  can be used in an adverse way.
 If we can artificially modify cellular level Telomers to induce cancer, then it becomes illegal. Using CRISPR Cas 9 to cut short Telomers for e.g...Has this been researched by Watchdog groups and the medical field?

Comment: If this is still not appropriate please let me know.